# Couldn't load tmx

Tags: libgdx, tmx

I'm using `libgdx` in my 2D platformer game project for college task. For now I'm confused with loading tiledmap in libgdx. I have a big tmx map with size of 11400x1500 pixels and 30x30 tile size. Also an image with same pixel size which I load it in image layer. I try to load it but libgdx shows nothing.
My question is how to load single big tmx map or should I divide the map into several segment/section? Because I've tried other small tmx (3000x1500). If the tmx is divided then how to load them as one stage?

```
public class Layarloh implements Screen{
private JumatUtama game;
private TiledMap map;
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private OrthographicCamera kamera;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
private Viewport viewport;

public Layarloh(JumatUtama utama) {
    float l=Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),t=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    this.game = utama;

    loadstage();
    kamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    kamera.setToOrtho(false,l,t);
    kamera.update();
    viewport = new FitViewport(l/3,t/3,kamera);

}
public void loadstage(){
    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("stage/s11.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

}
public void stik(float dt){
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY))
        kamera.position.x +=100*dt;

}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stik(delta);
    kamera.position.set(550,550,0);
    kamera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(kamera);
    mapRenderer.render();
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    kamera.viewportWidth = viewport.getScreenWidth();
    kamera.viewportHeight = viewport.getScreenHeight();
    kamera.update();
}
```

Unitscale does nothing, the code above works on smaller size of tmx map.

## EDIT

Code above isn't working, and the below is working, notice the `maploader` is loading different tmx file, above code trying to load 11400x1500 pixel with 30x30 tile size, while code below trying to load 3800x1500 with 30x30 tile size, but I try to use the code below to load bigger tmx, its not working,

```
public class Layarloh implements Screen{
private JumatUtama game;
private TiledMap map;
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private OrthographicCamera kamera;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;

public Layarloh(JumatUtama utama) {
    float l=Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),t=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    this.game = utama;

    loadstage();
    kamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    kamera.setToOrtho(false,l,t);
    kamera.position.set(550,550,0);
    kamera.update();

}

public void loadstage(){
    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("stage/segmen1.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);

}
public void stik(float dt){
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ANY_KEY))
        kamera.position.x +=100*dt;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    stik(delta);
    kamera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(kamera);
    mapRenderer.render();
}
```

Comment: Does it show anything on the console? Try enabling the logger.

Comment: kamera.position.x +=100*dt; Just try disabling it for now and see what happens.

Comment: kamera.position.set(550,550,0); Can you also try using 0, 0, 0 here rather than 550, 550, 0?

Comment: kamera.position.x is just for testing scrollable background when I press any key, and it works fine, kamera.position.set is to set the camera so I can see picture, here's my stage1.png [link](https://app.box.com/s/b9zjs43w6eeo3lmxa6rad5gnapcz5n2p) its size is 11400x1500 pixels

Comment: Have you tried with smaller map just to check it works or not?

Comment: load the smaller map is works, but thats make me to divide the map, and if I divide the map, how I can load all of them as one?

Comment: Rather than loading all at once which eats up a lot of resources, load the new map when you reach corner of a map. You can get that using map properties that where the end of map is. As soon as player reaches end, load a new map.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and this should fix it.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    kamera.position.set(x, y, z);
    kamera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(kamera);
    mapRenderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    kamera.viewportWidth = width;
    kamera.viewportHeight = height;
    kamera.update();
}
```

**EDIT**
In the original code, OP was missing `kamera.update()` statement. And also the resize method. That is something which causes trouble when displaying the tiled map properly as you need to update the camera at every iteration of render.

Comment: I've updated the question with including your code but still doesn't work, the code I've updated is my `PlayScreen` _class_

Comment: Why should it fix it? This is only the less useful part of an answer.

Comment: Because the solution was missing camera.update() method, OP edited his question now.

Comment: @msw I have edited my solution and given an explanation. :)